# How to remove a classname from the lastChild of an element using EXTJs

Tags: extjs

This may be super easy to crack, but I'm just not getting this to work:
I want to remove a class from the child node: I'm accessing the lastchild like below:
code:

```
Ext.select(".item").elements[0].lastChild
```

o/p:

```
<table class="abc test hide test123">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to remove the `class="hide`" and replace it with `class="show"`, so it'll render:

```
<table class="abc test show test123">
      <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

here is how the entire structure looks:

```
<div class="item">
   <div></div>
<div class="abc test hide"></div>
<div class="abc5643"></div>
<div class="abide"></div>
<table class="abc test hide test123">
   <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td></td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

so `<table>` is the lastchild of parent class`item`.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2llj)

After replace:
[image: after replace]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but im not sure if this will work for me. When I do: ```Ext.select('#aaa').elements[0].classList``` I get this as o/p: ```DOMTokenList ["item", value: "item"]``` and applying ```remove``` on that wont remove what I'm looking to remove.

Comment: yes I do: Ext.select('.item').elements[0].classList  and not by ```id``` and I cannot use ```i``` since its dynamically generated

Comment: it's only using `ExtJS` for the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

with `ExtJS` it works alike this (compared to DOM manipulation with `JS`):

```
Ext.select(".item > *:last-child").removeCls("hide").addCls("show");
```

^ that's only recommended when running against plain HTML markup, not ExtJS components.